# Node JS Not Broadcasting To Sender

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm starting the beginning of a two player game node js app and I'm trying to get the client/server working with nodejs.  The issue is when I broadcast the message with socket.io it goes to all connections but not the sender. I can't figure out why socket.broadcast.emit would not broadcast to the sender.

https://github.com/...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to broadcast the message to all connections you should use `io.emit`